# Django signals permissions with db.models

Tags: python, django, permissions, signals

I encounter the following problem when I try to create a app_B/model_B using signals.post_save sent by a creation of app_A/model_A:

app_B/models.py:

```
   from django.db import models
   from django.db.models import signals
   from app_A.models import model_A

   class model_B(models.Model):
       item = models.OneToOneField(model_A, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

   def create_model_B(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
       if created:
           model_B.objects.create(item=instance)

   signals.post_save.connect(create_model_B, sender=model_A, weak=False, dispatch_uid='models.create_model_B')
```

As simple as that, in my template the model_A form works perfectly, and the post_save creates automatically model B as well when I'm logged as a staff user.

As non-staff user (but not anonymous), it does not work: model_A and model_B are not created. It returns the HttpResponseRedirect of the model_A view, whatever the permissions are setup right for those apps. I don't know how to debug that either ...

Comment: Does it hit the signal `create_model_B` though ? You can put a print statement or a pdb to see what the values are

Comment: After lot of hours trying to get some logs, which where unsuccessful, I realized that the form in the model_A template does not have all the fields (some fields are reserved for the superuser, using `{% if request.user.is_staff %}`). Even if these fields have a "default" indicated, or a `null=True, blank=True`, the post_save does not work if the user is not staff ...
Is that a normal behavior ?